# Laravel - How to save a task with it's given class and properties and fetch it every minute again?

Tags: laravel

#### Goal:

I want to check if a specific job can be processed every minute.

For that, I want to use Task Scheduling.

However, I'm not sure how to solve it with my API end goal of:

```
SmsNotificaton::send($user, new OrderReceived($order));
```

How would you do this?

---

#### Explination:

I want to save some bucks by not sending an SMS directly to the user, only after 15 minutes went past and the status of the order didn't change.

Inside of `new OrderReceived($order)` I'm going to have a `handle` method. That method simply checks if the order status has changed or not. If changed, we send an SMS via my `SmsGateway`.

---

#### Problem:

How would you save the data of `$user` and `new OrderReceived($order)` in the **database**, so that you can call a **cron command every minute**, to fetch the old data of `$user` and `new OrderReceived($order)` again, to check if it is sendable?

It should be very similar to how the Laravel queue system works, but I tried to understand how serialization works, but I cannot grasp how the dispatcher saves the data and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is use Jobs & Queues built-in in laravel

You will need to create a new Job for example `CheckStatusThenSendSMSJob()` which when dispatched will check if order status changed or it should send message

Then instead of sending a message you need to Dispatch A job with a delay

`CheckStatusThenSendSMSJob($order)::dispatch->delay(now()->addMinutes(15));`

Check more about queues and delayed dispatch in laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#delayed-dispatching

Also make sure that you actually setup your queue to run in background (in a different process) by either using redis driver or database driver for queues ( By default laravel installation runs queues once they are called synchronously)

Comment: I think I overcomplicated my problem and I think you are right. Give me some minutes to think about it.